# How find this limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2}{1^4}+1)(\frac{2}{2^4}+1)(\frac{2}{3^4}+1)\cdots(\frac{2}{n^4}+1)$

Tags: number-theory, limits, infinite-product

> How to Find this limit
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2}{1^4}+1\right)\left(\dfrac{2}{2^4}+1\right)\left(\dfrac{2}{3^4}+1\right)\cdots\left(\dfrac{2}{n^4}+1\right)$$

see  [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cprod_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%281%2B2%2Fn%5E4%29)

I remeber in sack have solve this follow problem: But I can't find it
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^4}+1\right)$$
May be we use same methods can solve it.

Comment: Still no personal input. You might want to show how you prove the 1+1/n^4 case and why the method does not carry through.

Comment: try to use riemann integral.for this you must make a little change in what u've written.

Comment: @user115608 Did you check that this suggestion is not a deadend?

Comment: @Did of course!taking log and then writing as a riemann sum can be useful!

Comment: @user115608 After taking the logs, one gets a Riemann sum on $(1,+\infty)$ with steps of length $1$ of the function $f:t\to\log(1+1/t^4)$ or $f:t\to\log(1+2/t^4)$. How to use this to compute the product?

Comment: **Hint:** Use the infinite product for $\sin$ function: $\displaystyle \sin \pi x = \pi x \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$ and, $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{x^4}{n^4}\right) = \left(1+\frac{ix^2}{n^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{ix^2}{n^2}\right)$

Comment: @r9m: I see that you already gave the hint I left to math110 in a comment to Did's answer.

Comment: Still not willing to play by the rules?

Answer (score 10):

(*Note to the reader:* If you find this answer rather terse, then, first, you are right and, second, I suggest that you read the comment thread.)

$$2\pi^2x^2\cdot\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^4}{n^4}\right)=\cosh(\pi\sqrt2x)-\cos(\pi\sqrt2x)$$

Comment: @math110/chinamath Sure--as soon as the OP adds some personal input to their question (and [some vaguely related formula] + [but then I can't] or something similar, does not count).

Comment: @chinamath/math110 Why did you delete your previous comment?

Comment: at this rate will we ever see a solution or will it stay like a typical [Cleo](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/97378/cleo)ish answer ?

Comment: @r9m You are asking a real question. Ideal scenario: the OP takes on your hint and pushes it to the result in my post, or at least partways, then I complete my post (which is not an answer at present, despite the upvotes) and everything ends fine. Reality scenario: the OP will stay silent, hoping for some person to post a full answer, as it happened with their N previous flat-statement-of-problem questions. At present, (I might be wrong but) I see no reason to be this person.

Comment: Fair enough !! I understand ...

Comment: I've posted and deleted a full derivation of the formula. So anyone with a reputation of more than 10K can see that Did's formula is correct. I can undelete it, if it becomes appropriate.

Comment: why deleted,dear robjohn

Comment: @math110: I didn't want to undermine Did's desire to see the question improved. However, I will give this hint: I used the [product representation of the sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Product_representations_of_functions) due to Euler.

Comment: The sine hint is in @r9m's comment for 7 hours, for all to see.

Comment: @Did: yeah, I noticed that after I posted my comment.